# Как сделать рекурсию, которая работает как вложенные циклы?

Tags: javascript, циклы, рекурсия, числа

Задача в том, чтобы функция возвращала числа от 3-х до 20-ти значности. При чём число нужно обрабатывать по каждой цифре, а потом "склеивать" в одно число (цифра должна быть не менее предыдущей).

Получилось создать работающий код, но проблема в том, что нужно сделать много вложенных циклов (решение O(n^n) приблизительно, хотя для n^3 выдаёт 109 итераций), а моё решение не обрабатывает "вложенность" и работает только при ручном изменении количества циклов. Объясните, пожалуйста, как создать такой код

```
function find(n, k) {
  if (n < k) return 0
  const res = []
  let count = 0
  for (let a = 1; a <= n / k; a++) {
    for (let b = a; b < 10; b++) {
      for (let c = b; c < 10; c++) {
        if (a <= b && b <= c && a + b + c === n) {
          res.push(a * 100 + b * 10 + c)
          count++
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return [count, res]
}
```

n - сумма цифр числа, k - значность

Comment: Можно пожалуйста, чуть более подробное описание задачи?

Comment: Вернуть массив, где [количество чисел, где каждая цифра не меньше предыдущей и их сумма равна n, а значность равна k; массив этих чисел]

Comment: В задаче надо было добавить три примера: 1)пример чисел на входе, 2) какой должен быть результат. В текущем виде непонятно зачем вообще возвращать `[count, ...]`, когда он равен `res.length` и почему первая строка возвращает не массив а число.

Comment: Погодите минутку. Как число может быть 20-ти значным и причём каждая цифра меньше предыдущей? Цифр всего 10 штук у нас, не может быть 20-ти значного числа, так чтобы цифры были одна меньше предыдушего. Максимальное такое число - это `9876543210`

Comment: И непонятно, что и как тут может работать. Когда первый цикл достигнет `a==10`, все вложенные циклы не сработают и `a++` будет вертеться впустую.

Comment: может, ведь цифра должна быть не меньше предыдущей, но может быть равна ей. Например, ввод fn(10, 3), а вывод будет 8,
  [
    118, 127, 136,
    145, 226, 235,
    244, 334
  ]

Comment: исправил, теперь первая строка возвращает пустой массив

Comment: в задаче была подсказка, что её решить можно рекурсией. Возможно ли изменить моё решение, чтобы  оно работало корректно?

Comment: @DanilaEgorenko А ноль может быть частью числа, или только 1-9?

Comment: 0 не может быть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекурсивное решение действительно очень простое. Вот как оно может выглядеть на Python. Вместо создания списка чисел здесь я их просто
вывожу.

На каждом уровне рекурсии наша задача - создать число с суммой цифр summ и количеством цифр num, начинающееся с цифры не менее dmin.

Если принцип понятен, то на JS перевести, наверное, нетрудно (у меня с лёту не заработало, как в JS вообще отлаживать?)

```
def buildSum(summ, num, dmin, curr):
    if num == 0:
        if summ == 0:
            print(curr)
    else:
        for d in range(dmin, min(summ, 9) + 1):
            buildSum(summ - d, num - 1, d, curr*10 + d)

buildSum(10, 3, 1, 0)

118
127
136
145
226
235
244
334
```

Comment: Я переписал под JS, действительно эффективное решение)

Answer (score 0):

Переписал решение [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo) на JS, вдруг, кому понадобиться

```
function buildSum(summ, num, dmin, curr) {
    if (!num && !summ) console.log(curr)
    for (let d = dmin; d < Math.min(summ, 9) + 1; d++) {
      buildSum(summ - d, num - 1, d, curr * 10 + d)
    }
}
```

Comment: Учтите ещё, что для 20-значных чисел в JS понадобится использовать BigInt - видимо, curr * 10**n** + BigInt(d) и т.д.

Answer (score -2):

число состоящее из 20 знаков вы будете решать очень долго. И по логике вашего ответа выше ваше число не может быть больше 10 знаков, так как иначе не выполняется условие что каждая последующая цифра числа больше предыдущей.
Если вы хотите решать данную задачу в лоб, то просто заведите один цикл фор внутри которого сделайте цикл while который будет определять количество цифр в вашем числе. Для этого делите ваше число которое вы проверяете на 10 и запоминайте остаток от деления, который и будет вашим числом, после чего проверяйте полученные числа на выполнение условия вашей задачи. Таким образом Вам не нужна будет рекурсия и вы все сделаете с использованием всего двух циклов. Но вообще данная задача должна решаться иметь решение без прямого перебора.

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь оставлять примеры кода при ответе на вопросы, насколько это возможно

Comment: может, например, 99999999999999999999, его сумма 180. К тому же брутфорс без оптимизации будет оооочень долгим